# Spring Cloud Config client doesn't get values from server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have been following [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration) tutorial from Baeldung in setting up a Spring Cloud Config server and client. I believe I have set up the server correctly since going to http://localhost:8888/service-config/development/master will seemingly correctly show the json with the user.role defined:

```
{"name":"service-config","profiles":["development"],"label":"master","version":"d30a6015a6b8cb1925f6e61cee22721f331e5783","state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"file:///C:.../git/service-config-data/service-config-development.properties","source":{"user.role":"Developer"}},{"name":"file:///C:.../git/service-config-data/service-config.properties","source":{"user.role":"Developer"}}]}
```

However, I cannot seem to correctly connect the Spring Cloud Config client to the server - the client fails to run with cannot resolve placeholder errors on the `@Value("${user.role}")` annotation. I've tried adding a default value to the annotation and then manually refreshing the values (using the `@refreshscope` annotation), but to no avail.

I've looked at the debug and trace logs by running the tools with `--debug --trace` flags but I cannot find when/if the client is making the call to the server and which config-data .properties file the server is actually looking for. I am a bit lost on how to proceed.

---

Here is my server `application.properties`:

```
spring.application.name=service-config
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:///${user.home}/git/service-config-data
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=false
spring.security.user.name=root
spring.security.user.password=toor
```

And inside the `service-config-data` folder, there are files with this inside:

```
user.role=Developer
```

I have tried files called service-config.properties, service-config-client.properties, service-config-development.properties, and service-config-client-development.properties, and none of them seem to pull through the `user.role`.

Here is my client:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RefreshScope
public class ServiceConfigClient {

    @Value("${user.role:unknown}")
    private String role;

    @RequestMapping(
      value = "/whoami/{username}", 
      method = RequestMethod.GET, 
      produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public String whoami(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
        return String.format("Hello! You're %s and you'll become a(n) %s...\n", username, role);
    }
}
```

And my client `bootstrap.properties`:

```
spring.application.name=service-config-client
spring.profiles.active=development
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
spring.cloud.config.username=root
spring.cloud.config.password=toor

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

---

How do I correctly connect the client to the server so that it can successfully pull the config data? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was fixed by adding `spring.cloud.config.name=service-config` to the `bootstrap.properties` of the service-config-client as well as adding `spring-cloud-config-client` to and removing `spring-cloud-config-server` from my `pom.xml`

Comment: Could you please guide me here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66922674/unable-to-fetch-property-value-from-the-config-server ?

Answer (score 1):

There is confusion about client service name and corresponding property sources in config server.

You need to do one of the following:

1. Change client service name:

```
//client bootstrap.properties
spring.application.name=service-config
```

2. Change folder name in git repo from `service-config` to `service-config-client`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the first option but that didn't have any affect - I still get unknown instead of the pulled through value of "Developer". For the second option, which folder are you referring to? The service-config folder is for the server, service-config-client is the client, and service-config-data is the configuration storage. Which needs to be renamed?

Comment: @SWilliams Sorry I was not online more some hours. Good hear that your problem solved.