# Unable to fetch property value from the config server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server

I am learning Spring Boot v.2.3.9.RELEASE + Microservices project from here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7A_M8HkJG0

In this example, I am unable to fetch the details from the properties file using spring-cloud-config.

**spring-config-server**

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/techefx/environment-variable-repo.git

server:
  port: ${port:8888}
```

ConfigServerApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

property-access-service

PropertyAccessBean.java

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "property-file")
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PropertyAccessBean {
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

PropertyAccessValue.java

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PropertyAccessValue {
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

PropertyAccessServiceApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class PropertyAccessServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PropertyAccessServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need getter and setter for PropertyAccessBean's fields

Comment: @Md.KawserHabib - Hey, Thanks, I have added lambok annotation - data already, that gives me setter and getter, but issue is something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put (default-label: main) in yml file:

spring:
application:
name: techefx-spring-cloud-config-server
cloud:
config:
server:
git:
uri: https://github.com/techefx/environment-variable-repo.git
default-label: main

server:
port: ${port:8888}